# How can I create a default for a SQL Server column to insert just the last ten characters of NEWID()?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following DDL that my group mate executed to add a new column:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Question] ADD GlobalId VARCHAR (50) DEFAULT(NEWID());
```

I would now like to change this so that the default is just for the last eight characters of the NEWID() that's produced. Can someone tell me how I can drop the default and create a new default that does this. Thanks very much.

Comment: Is GlobalId is new Property Of your table

Comment: GlobalId is an existing column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give an idea, `select substring(reverse(newid()),0,8);` will produce the value what you require.

Probably `ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Question] ADD GlobalId VARCHAR (50) DEFAULT(substring(reverse(newid()),0,8));` would do for you.

**EDITED** 
*@Melina : How would I drop the existing default and add this as a new default ?*

1. you have to first create a temp table from existing.
   `select col1,col2, ... substring(reverse(GlobalId, 0, 8)) into TEMP_T from [dbo].[Question];`
2. Drop table `drop table [dbo].[Question];`
3. Create a new table with all existing fields but new alter
   `create table [dbo].[Question] (col1 type1, col2 type2 ..., GlobalId VARCHAR (8) DEFAULT(substring(reverse(newid()),0,8)));`
4. **Insert data from TEMP_T to the newly created table**.

Comment: How would I drop the existing default and add this as a new default ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this simply by this way

```
Declare @varNewId as nvarchar(50)
set @varNewId =( select RIGHT(NewID(),3))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Question] ADD GlobalId VARCHAR (50) DEFAULT(@varNewId);
```